# Only show tables with certain patterns in mysql "show tables"

Tags: mysql, pagination, show

There are too many tables in a db. how can I only show tables with certain patterns? Or is there a way I can do paging like "| more" in shell command?

Comment: not for mysql, but for oracle, you can do "select * from cat where table_name like '%xxxx'". the same functionality must exist for mysql

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
show tables like 'pattern';
```

Comment: I also found `show tables like '%pattern%';` works too : )

Comment: @michaelmcgurk,  the % is the wildcard in any like statement.  Therefore a'r was correct...the pattern can be anything you are searching for, including wildcards.

Comment: What is the way if I want to SHOW TABLES LIKE 'xxx_%'    but I don't want the underscore character as a wildcard... ?  

SHOW TABLES LIKE 'xx#_%' ESCAPE '#' don't work for me...

Comment: If you want to use the same command on dbfs Azure Databricks, instead of the typical SQL wildcard `%` use `*`

Answer (score 9):

- use **show tables like 'pattern'**
- pattern is a string using wildcard characters "%","_"
- % matches any number of characters, even zero characters.
- _ matches exactly one character.

**for example:**

- *show tables like 'test%'* will filter tables such as "test1,testF,test111,testFoo"
- *show tables like 'test_'* will filter tables such as "test1,testF"

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use `show tables`, you can also query `information_schema.TABLES` using any filter.

Comment: Can you give an example or link? Where is the information_schema.TABLES located?

Comment: Information_schema is a MySQL system DB. You can check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html for details

Comment: SELECT * from information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'oc_%';

Answer (score 0):

In Spark SQL you need to use an asterisk symbol, `SHOW tables LIKE '*table_name*`

Answer (score -4):

this can be used to have a glimpse of all the tables

```
select * from tab;
```

and identify the columns names. Thereafter, use

```
select * from tab where tname like '%D_';
```

Comment: This is incorrect. This would query a table, not show tables that would have a pattern name for a table